# IE8 won't render input properly with border-box

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, border-box

I have a form with a text-input, I gave that text-input the css-property `box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; padding-left: 28px`. According to all documentation I can find about `border-box` IE8 is supposed to support this value for `box-sizing` (and is in fact *the way IE8 renders box-model in quirks-mode*), and should always keep this input at 100% width, despite it having a padding on the left. However, it appears to just add the padding to the width anyway. You can see this at http://theater.dierclients.com/assets/html, in the purple sidebar.

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: It works for me in IE8 emulated by IE9

Comment: Perhaps this is an advertising attempt?

Comment: It most certainly isn't an advertising attempt, I'm sharing a work in progress on my dev-server with no links wired up, I thought it'd be easier then copy-pasting all the code-blurbs (especially since some of it is in Compass instead of css). The weird thing is that what appears to be going wrong is that *actual* IE8 (as opposed to emulating) uses "IE7 Standards" document-mode to render because of the html5-doctype.

Answer (score 4):

`box-sizing` is a CSS3 property. It is not implemented in IE8 directly. You need to use this syntax:

`-ms-box-sizing`

See http://erik.eae.net/archives/2008/03/10/21.48.10/
and http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

Note that this is similar to the `-moz-box-sizing` that you will need to use for certain versions of Firefox. See the Browser Compatibility section of this page for details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: caniuse claims the prefix is not needed

Comment: @JanDvorak I know, I posted the link ;). But the opinion appears to be divided...

Answer (score 0):

I can assure you that no prefix is needed for IE 8. Please check for yourself.